# How to change a .dbf file AND its associated .mdx file with Python?

Tags: python, indexing, mdx, dbf

I want to delete some rows of a .dbf file. It's clear for me how to do this with Python for example with the dbf-module. However, the .dbf file has an index .mdx file associated with it. If I change the .dbf file, how can I change its associated .mdx file accordingly? Is this functionality supported by the .dbf module? If not, how can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's more than one python module that attempts to work with dbf files -- which one are you using?

Comment: Sadly, I do not know of any Python dbf modules that work with any of the index files (.idx, .cdx, .mdx).

Comment: I'm using this dbf module: http://pythonhosted.org/dbf/

Answer (score 2):

The [`dbf`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dbf)* library in question does not support index files of any type.  If you have access to the original program you could use it to rebuild the indices after you modify the `.dbf` file itself.

---

*Disclosure:  I am the author of the `dbf` library.